# How do you load a frame into the HamburgerMenu?

Tags: c#, wpf, mahapps.metro, hamburger-menu

I'm trying to create a simple app using the MahApps.Metro `HamburgerMenu` control. So far I've set up my Main Window as described in the examples:

```
<Controls:MetroWindow x:Class="HamburgerDemo.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:HamburgerDemo"
        xmlns:Controls="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Controls:MetroWindow.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="HamburgerMenuItem" DataType="{x:Type Controls:HamburgerMenuGlyphItem}">
            <Grid Height="48">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="48" />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Margin="12"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       Text="{Binding Glyph}" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
                           VerticalAlignment="Center"
                           FontSize="16"
                           Text="{Binding Label}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Controls:MetroWindow.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Controls:HamburgerMenu ItemTemplate="{StaticResource HamburgerMenuItem}">
            <Controls:HamburgerMenu.ItemsSource>
                <Controls:HamburgerMenuItemCollection>
                    <Controls:HamburgerMenuGlyphItem Glyph="1" Label="Page 1"/>
                    <Controls:HamburgerMenuGlyphItem Glyph="2" Label="Page 2"/>
                </Controls:HamburgerMenuItemCollection>
            </Controls:HamburgerMenu.ItemsSource>
        </Controls:HamburgerMenu>
    </Grid>
</Controls:MetroWindow>
```

I'd like each menu button to link to a specific `Page` which will be loaded into a `Frame` when clicked, however I can't figure out how to do this.

I noticed that the `HamburgerMenuGlyphItem` does have a property `TargetPageType`, and I imagine that this might be the key but I have no idea how to use this.

If there are better methods to loading content using this control or different design patterns I would love to hear them.

Answer (score 2):

I've done it like this, in code-behind, if I understood you right. If it's not what you meant to just tell me!

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="Stackoverflow.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Stackoverflow"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        xmlns:Controls="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
  <Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="HamburgerMenuItem" DataType="{x:Type Controls:HamburgerMenuGlyphItem}">
      <Grid Height="48">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="48" />
          <ColumnDefinition />
          <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Margin="12"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       Text="{Binding Glyph}" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
                           VerticalAlignment="Center"
                           FontSize="16"
                           Text="{Binding Label}" />
        <Button Grid.Column="2" Click="Button_Click" Tag="{Binding Tag}">Go</Button>
      </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
  </Window.Resources>
  <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
      <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Controls:HamburgerMenu ItemTemplate="{StaticResource HamburgerMenuItem}">
      <Controls:HamburgerMenu.ItemsSource>
        <Controls:HamburgerMenuItemCollection>
          <Controls:HamburgerMenuGlyphItem Glyph="1" Label="Page 1" Tag="Page1.xaml"/>
          <Controls:HamburgerMenuGlyphItem Glyph="2" Label="Page 2" Tag="Page2.xaml"/>
        </Controls:HamburgerMenuItemCollection>
      </Controls:HamburgerMenu.ItemsSource>
    </Controls:HamburgerMenu>

    <Frame x:Name="_TheFrame" Grid.Column="2"/>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs** (code-behind)

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string targetView = ((Button)sender).Tag.ToString();
        _TheFrame.Source = new Uri(targetView, UriKind.Relative);
    }
}
```

**Page1.xaml**

```
<Page x:Class="Stackoverflow.Page1"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Stackoverflow"
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
      Title="Page1">
  <Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="PAGE 1" FontSize="24" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
  </Grid>
</Page>
```

**Page2.xaml**

```
<Page x:Class="Stackoverflow.Page2"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Stackoverflow"
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
      Title="Page2">
  <Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="PAGE 2" FontSize="24" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
  </Grid>
</Page>
```

Answer (score 1):

I answer in another one to make it easier to read.

Another approach would be using MVVM. For this I've come up with this. If it works for you and you'd like some explanations tell me. I'm kind of lazy now, so I've also used the Prism framework to take the DelegateCommand and the PropertyChanged base object.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Controls:MetroWindow x:Class="Stackoverflow.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Stackoverflow"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        BorderThickness="2"
        BorderBrush="DarkGray"
        xmlns:Controls="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
  <Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainWindowViewModel/>
  </Window.DataContext>
  <Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="HamburgerMenuItem" DataType="{x:Type Controls:HamburgerMenuGlyphItem}">
      <Grid Height="48">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="48" />
          <ColumnDefinition />
          <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Margin="12"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       Text="{Binding Glyph}" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
                           VerticalAlignment="Center"
                           FontSize="16"
                           Text="{Binding Label}" />
        <Button Grid.Column="2" 
                Command="{Binding DataContext.NavigateCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Controls:MetroWindow}}" 
          CommandParameter="{Binding Tag}">Go</Button>
      </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
  </Window.Resources>
  <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
      <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Controls:HamburgerMenu ItemTemplate="{StaticResource HamburgerMenuItem}">
      <Controls:HamburgerMenu.ItemsSource>
        <Controls:HamburgerMenuItemCollection>
          <Controls:HamburgerMenuGlyphItem Glyph="1" Label="Page 1" Tag="Page1.xaml"/>
          <Controls:HamburgerMenuGlyphItem Glyph="2" Label="Page 2" Tag="Page2.xaml"/>
        </Controls:HamburgerMenuItemCollection>
      </Controls:HamburgerMenu.ItemsSource>
    </Controls:HamburgerMenu>

    <Frame Grid.Column="2" Source="{Binding FrameSource}"/>
  </Grid>
</Controls:MetroWindow>
```

**MainWindowViewModel.cs**

```
using Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Commands;
using Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Mvvm;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace Stackoverflow
{
    public class MainWindowViewModel : BindableBase
    {
        private string _FrameSource;

        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            NavigateCommand = new DelegateCommand<string>(OnNavigateCommandExecute);
        }

        public string FrameSource
        {
            get { return _FrameSource; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _FrameSource, value); }
        }

        public ICommand NavigateCommand { get; private set; }

        private void OnNavigateCommandExecute(string frameSource)
        {
            FrameSource = frameSource;
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Before clicking the buttons]
[image: After click the Page 1 "Go" button]

[image]